# Max distance a character can move while slowed factoring in anything

Tags: dnd-4e

I have heard mixed information on this and I am now looking for clarification as it will affect the effectiveness of a build I'm currently working on.  When a creature is slowed at the start of his turn, what is the absolute maximum distance he can move (excluding teleport).  Please factor in everything such as if he tries to run, double moving, attacks with built-in shifting, etc.  It is my understanding that he'll be able to move 2 squares total, but I'm looking for confirmation on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slowed means that its speed becomes 2 if it was higher than that (*Rules Compendium*, page 233).  That's it.  Recalculate the creature's movement (including flying, walking, swimming, etc.) based on this new speed.  Any powers that don't explicitly use its speed are unaffected.

- Double move: 2 × Speed = 4 squares.
- Run: Speed + 2 = 4 squares.
- Double run: 2 × (Speed + 2) = 8 squares.
- Attacks with built-in shifting (without reference to speed) are unaffected.
- Movements without reference to speed are unaffected.

For example, if a Deathjump Spider is slowed, it can still use its Prodigious Leap because even though its walk and climb speed were 6 and are now 2, the power does not refer to its speed.

> **Prodigious Leap** (move; encounter)
>
> The deathjump spider shifts up to 10 squares.

Comment: I don't have the compendium.  Does this match what is in the phb page 277.  That definition said the following: "Your speed becomes 2. This speed applies to all your movement modes, but it does not apply to teleportation or to a pull, a push, or a slide. You can’t increase your speed above 2, and your speed doesn’t increase if it was lower than 2. If you’re slowed while moving, stop moving if you have already moved 2 or more squares."  It was the last part of this definition about stop moving that I was wondering about.

Comment: That same detail is in the Compendium, just more succinctly: _If a creature is subjected to this condition while it is moving using any of its speeds, it must stop if it has already moved at least 2 squares._